# Regex: Everything but TAGs

Tags: html, regex, tags

I try do get all strings/text except html tags. 
ex.

```
<html><head><title>test</title></head><body><p>hi there</p></body></html>
 -->
"test hi there"
```

First I tried to make a regular expression that finds all html tags: `(<.*?>)` . After that I tried to invert the regexp `((?!<.*?>).)*` - but this expression doesn't work :( 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: See that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: I edited your question to format it. You break it. Please look at the formatting help you have in the toolbar !

Comment: If you're using php it has a very nice function `strip_tags`

Comment: I would ask what programming language you're using the regex in, but it doesn't matter. Regex is the wrong tool for this job in ***every*** programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of matching everything but tags, you should try to match only the tags and remove them from the string so that your result is left over.

```
var str = "<html><head><title>test</title></head><body><p>hi there</p></body></html>";
var res = str.replace(/(<[^>]+>)+/g, " ");
```

You might need to `.replace(/\s+/g, " ")` and trim the result to get the expected output.

---

Btw, it is a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1048572) to try matching all HTML syntax with regular expressions. Instead, you might want to use a [DOM parser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOMParser) and get the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent) of the resulting document.

Answer (score 1):

This is the regex pattern you want:

```
>([^<]*)<
```

Using regex match, you will get an array of strings. It you put all the even strings together (like *below*) you will get what you want. [For more info see this.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

```
//This is not a real language!
//Syntax based on Java and Javascript

String function getHtmlText(String html) {
 String str = "";
 String[] arr = match(html, "/>([^<]*)</");
 Int i = arr.length;

 while(i) {
  str += arr[i];
  i   -= 2; //Because we want every even value
 }

 return str;
}
```

Or use DOM element's `textContent` attribute. [See this.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent)

Hope it helps, m93a :D

Comment: What about `<p>some random text <em>here</em> and some more text</p>`. [HTML is too complex to be parsed by regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: No, it's not, it will output "some random text here and some more text".

Comment: But I like the Q&A you posted. It's a pitty I can't upvote :D

Comment: m93a, it will only do that if you loop over all the matches.

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig Yep, every even match is the text. Thanks for reaction, I will add it to my answer.

Comment: This will not match text outside tags. The question asks for all text except text the tags, therefore, it should include text outside the tags as well. eg: hi <p> there </p> should match "hi there", not just "there"

Answer (score 0):

Use below expression and replace all the tags with an empty string ""

```
(\<[A-Za-z =":/.]+\>)|(\</[A-Za-z]+\>)
```

If the HTML tags are

```
<B>Bold 
<P>This is a sample text</P>
</B>
<A HREF="http://www.google.com">Click Here</A>
```

Replacing above expression with empty string produces below result

```
Bold 
This is a sample text

Click Here
```

Comment: FYI, angle brackets (`<` and `>`) have no special meaning in regexes, and don't need to be escaped.  In some flavors, `\<` and `\>` match word boundaries, so by escaping the angle brackets you're completely changing their meaning.